# Hello, how do I pass the value of a controller variable to a visualforce component?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I want to test on "if" if the value inside bemSize is greater than 1, but salesforce does not recognize the bemSize variable, in the code it is simpler to understand, thanks for any help /o/
Controller:

```
global with sharing class CoberturasOrcamentoController  {
    private List<BemSegurado__c> bemSegurado2;
    public Integer bemSize;
    private Boolean varLMI;     
    private BemSegurado__c bemSeguradoUniq;
    private BemSegurado__c lmiuni;
 }

public List <BemSegurado__c> getBemSegurado2(){
        if(bemSegurado2==null){
        bemSegurado2 = [
            SELECT Id, Name, NomeProprietario__c, ValorRisco__c, CPFCNPJ__c, TipoConstrucao__c, CEP__c, LocalRisco__c, ClasseBonusAnterior__c, Ocupacao__c, 
            QuantidadeSinistros__c, Identificacao__c, InformacoesComplementares__c, CodigoFrota__c, CI__c, NovaClasseBonus__c,
            ValorMercado__c, RecordType.DeveloperName, Nome__c, NomeBem__c, Marca__c, Modelo__c, Combustivel__c, AnoFabricacao__c, AnoModelo__c, Cor__c, 
            Placa_UF__c, TabelaFIPE__c, LotacaoMaxima__c, Chassi__c, Renavam__c, Rastreador__c, Sexo__c, DataNascimento__c, IdentificacaoMatricula__c,
            Certificado__c, SalarioBase__c,LMI_Unico__c
            FROM BemSegurado__c 
            WHERE Oportunidade__c =: opportunityId
            ];
            bemSize = bemSegurado2.size();//here the variable receives the size of the list

        }
        return bemSegurado2;
    }

 public Boolean getvarLMI(){
       lmiuni = getbemSeguradoUniq();
        if(lmiuni == null){
            varLMI = false;
            return false;
        } else {
            varLMI = true;
            return true;
        }
        
    }
```

VFC:

```
<apex:component access="global" controller="CoberturasOrcamentoController">
    <apex:attribute name="quoteIdValue" type="String" description="This is the Id of the quote" assignTo="{!quoteId}" access="global" />
    <apex:attribute name="accountIdValue" type="String" description="This is the Id of the Account related to this quote" assignTo="{!accountId}" access="global" />
    <apex:attribute name="opportunityIdValue" type="String" description="This is the Id of the Opportunity related to this quote" assignTo="{!opportunityId}" access="global" />
    
<html>
<div>
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!if(varLMI==false && bemSize>1 , true ,false)}"><!--here salesforce says it doesn't recognize obemSize...I don't understand why
-->
                        <apex:repeat value="{!Cobertura}" var="cob">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align: left">{!cob.BemSegurado__r.Identificacao__c}</td>
                                <td style="text-align: left">{!cob.Opcoes_de_Coberturas__r.Name}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </apex:repeat>
                     </apex:outputPanel>
</div>
</html>
```

the mistake:
Unknown property 'CoberturasOrcamentoController.bemSize'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visualforce (well, the renderer that converts your Visualforce into HTML that ends up getting sent to your browser) doesn't have a way to access the variables of a class directly. Instead, Visualforce accesses things by calling a method.

Most times (except for methods given in the `action` parameter of things like `<apex:page>` and `<apex:pageButton>`), Salesforce will try to call a method whose name stars with "get". This is an example of "convention instead of configuration". In your example, you used `bemSize` in your merge expression, so Salesforce is looking for a method called `getbemSize()` in your controller to call.

A class variable with a "getter" (and/or a setter) method makes it a *property*. Since you have no `getbemSize()` method, Salesforce gives you the error that it can't find a *property* named `bemSize`.

The solution here is to make `bemSize` a property by defining a getter. You could write that by hand, but Salesforce gives us a shortcut. By simply including `{get; set;}` (or, minimally, `{get;}`) in the declaraction of `bemSize`, Salesforce will automatically create the appropriate getter/setter behind the scenes.

So change from

```
public Integer bemSize;
```

to

```
public Integer bemSize {get; set;}
```

You should also look through [Apex Properties](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm) for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: +1 for the link !

Comment: thank you! Your explanation also helped a lot to understand how it works, I will definitely take a look at the link you passed

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `get ; set;` in order to access apex class members on the client side. This could be similar to what you're already doing with varLMI. You defined a getter getvarLMI that returns the value of varLMI.

or you can simply mark the property as get set.

Update line #3 to

```
public Integer bemSize{ get; set; }
```

Comment: wow
thank you!!!!!